# Run external exectuable in background and intercept ofstream

Tags: c++, qt, ofstream, qprocess

From a Qt/C++ application, how do you run an external executable (with GUI, no command line interface) in the background, and intercept its ofstream?

The external executable takes a file of a certain type, and converts and outputs it to another file.
I want to prevent the new file from being written and read the contents directly into my application instead.

I tried the following:

```
    bool success = true;
    auto *converter = new QProcess(this);
    converter->start("converter.exe", QStringList()<<path);

    if (converter->waitForStarted() && converter->waitForReadyRead()) {
        for (; !converter->atEnd() && success; lineNr++) {
            success = line(converter->readLine());
        }
    }
    else {
        error = "Failed to start converter.";
        success = false;
    }
    converter->waitForFinished();
```

But the executable is just run normally and outputs the new file.

Comment: Does `converter.exe` not have any command line option that lets you specify the output file name or that output should go to `stdout`?

Comment: @G.M. nope, there aren't any command line options, the output file name is always the original file name/path with a different extention.

Comment: Well, not an easy task. Just wait for the process to exit, read and delete the file.